# Multithreading does not work for bi-directional udp communication python

Tags: python, udp, python-multithreading

[Output at console server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUpSR.png)

I am trying to write bi-directional UDP communication using multithread but it crashes after sending two messages. Also i am new to threading so please post your solution on this.
Thanks

Server side:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import socket
from socket import *
import time
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime
from time import ctime
#broadcast works for this program
import netifaces
import os
import re
import struct
class cont():


    def get_msg(self):
        UDP = "192.168.1.27"
        port = 4343
        address = UDP, port
        self.sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.bind(address)
        while True:
            r = self.sock.recvfrom(1000)
            print("controller1: %s" % (r[0]))
            reply = input('Main controller  : ')
            client_address = r[1]
            self.sock.sendto(bytearray(reply, "utf-8"), client_address)
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.get_msg, args=(reply,))
            t2.start()
if __name__=='__main__':
    c=cont()
    #c.broad(msg="")
    c.get_msg()
```

Client side:

```
UDP=""
port=4343
address=UDP,port
client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while(True):
    msg=input("Controller1")
client.sendto(bytearray(msg,"utf-8"),address)
reply=client.recvfrom(1000)
recved=str(reply)
print("Main Controller:% s" % recved))
```

## Output required :

```
Server Console:

Client:b'hello'
Server:b'hi

Client Console:

Client: b'hello'
Server : (b'hi',('ip',port)
```

Comment: `get_msg` needs no parameter `reply`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to receive message from client side and then send a return reply to it like two way communication.

Comment: You are starting a new thread on every iteration in every thread? And there is no reading coordination between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TCP class I made for communicating with my robots, can be easily modified for UDP. Might seem like a lot of code, but it's what it takes for "reliable" "two way" communication, without blocking your main program. I use processes instead of threads because threads in python aren't "real" threads due to the global interpreter lock.

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event, Value
import traceback

class SocketComm(object):
    def __init__(self,port):
        self.address = ""
        self.otherAddress = object
        self.port = port
        self.finished = Value("b", True)
        self.inbox = Queue()
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.getMessagesProcess = Process(target=self.getMessages)
        self.getMessagesProcess._stop_event = Event()
        self.getMessagesProcess.daemon = True

        self.connected = False
        self.timeout = 3
        return

    def setupLine(self, addr):
        self.address = addr
        if self.address is "": #i.e. server on raspberry pi
            try:
                self.connection.settimeout(self.timeout)
                self.connection.bind((self.address, self.port))
                print("binding with port: " + str(self.port))
                self.connection.listen(1)
                self.connection, self.otherAddress = self.connection.accept()
                print("connected to client at: " + self.otherAddress[0])
            except socket.error as e:
                print(str(e))
                return False
        else:
            try:
                #print("connecting to port: " + str(self.port))
                self.connection.connect((self.address, self.port)) # i.e. client
                print("connected to server")
            except socket.error as e:
                #print(str(e))
                return False

        self.getMessagesProcess.start()
        self.connected = True
        self.finished.value = False
        print("inbox at: " + str(id(self.inbox)))
        return True

    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        try:
            self.connection.send(str.encode(msg))
            #print("sent: " + str(msg))
        except Exception as e:
            pass
            #print(str(e))
            #traceback.print_exc()
            #print("exception caught.")
        return

    def getMessages(self):
        #print("getting messages now")
        self.connection.settimeout(1)
        while(not self.finished.value):
            #print("checking inbox")
            #print("inbox length: " + str(len(self.inbox)))
            try:
                received = self.connection.recv(1024)
                decoded = received.decode('utf-8')
                if len(decoded) > 0:
                    if(decoded == "end"):
                        self.finished.value = True
                    else:
                        self.inbox.put(decoded)
                        print("received: " + str(decoded))
            except socket.error as e:
                if(type(e).__name__ == "timeout"):
                    pass
                else:
                    print("endpoint closed.")
                    self.finished.value = True
        return

    def closeConnection(self):
        if(self.connected):
            self.finished.value = True
            self.getMessagesProcess._stop_event.set()
            self.sendMessage("end")
            try:
                self.getMessagesProcess.join()
            except:
                print("process already finished.")
            self.connection.close()
        return



##
##if(__name__ == "__main__"):
##    robotClient = SocketComm(5555)
##    robotClient.setupLine("127.0.0.1")
##    while(robotClient.finished.value == False):
##        val = input("enter something: ")
##        if(len(val) > 0):
##            robotClient.sendMessage(val)
##
##
##if(__name__ == "__main__"):
##    try:
##        robotServer = SocketComm(5555)
##        print("waiting for client to connect...")
##        robotServer.setupLine("")
##        print("connected!")
##        while(robotServer.finished.value == False):
##            val = input("enter something: ")
##            if(len(val) > 0):
##                robotServer.sendMessage(val)
##    except:
##        pass
##    finally:
##        robotServer.closeConnection()
##        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: where are you calling your class in the if __main__? and also i have a multithreads used for my whole project so i was struck with this part of my code so at one port i am listening for clients and storing the data in database and other is this which is two way communication. Either two way or the client storing thread works. Both of them is not working together

Comment: At the bottom of the code is a fully executable example of the server and client - what do you mean where do I call this in the main? You can continue to use threads however in your program, this class works out of the box as a standalone module.

Comment: I see why you asked, I forgot I renamed this class to `SocketComm` from `Communicate`, and when I did that I did not refactor the class name in the commented example. It is fixed now.

Comment: where do we mention port  in robotclient.setup("")?

Comment: Gah, another edit I forgot to make in the commented example. If you look at the SocketComm `__init__` function, thats where it takes a port. Hang on and I will update the example.

Comment: so copy and paste the two "mains" in two separate python files, run them both, and if it works to your satisfaction please upvote the answer :)

Comment: Anyway thanks, but my answer needs multithreading :( but ill upvote for the post though.